# Open an external pdf file on a specific page

Tags: hyperref, pdf

I want to hyperlink to an external pdf file on a specific page. I have a solution to open the file but not on a specific page.

I have tried with `\href{./PR.I.OAT_Sensor_Assembly.pdf**\#=2**}{Reference 1}` and with `\href{./PR.I.OAT_Sensor_Assembly.pdf**\#page.#1**}{Reference 1}` and with `\href{./PR.I.OAT_Sensor_Assembly.pdf#page=2}{Reference 1}`. Nothing is working for now, is there a problem with my pdf viewer?

I'm also trying with the `pdfnewwindow` command to open a pdf file on a specific page on a new window.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{./PR.I.OAT_Sensor_Assembly.pdf{Reference 1}} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\href[page=4]{somepdf.pdf}{text}`  (the page number is the absolute page).

Comment: You are the best. Thank you.

Comment: One more question. How can I use both packages ?\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} and \usepackage[pdfnewwindow]{hyperref} at the same time?

Comment: `\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfnewwindow]{hyperref}`. Or use `\hypersetup` to set more options.

Comment: Hello. I apologize for reaching out again, but I would like to inquire if there is an option to open an external PDF document in a specific section. I have attempted to use \href[section=xy]{somepdf.pdf}{text}, but it doesn't seem to be working. Additionally, I'm facing another issue where each time a new PDF opens, the previous one closes. Is there a way to open the PDF in a new tab without closing the existing one?

Comment: do not misuse comments to get personal support. If you have a new question ask a new question. And be more specific, how should anyone know which applications you use or which targets an external PDF offers?